# Nextjs - importing next/document outside of pages/_document error

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, next.js

**I am getting this error during build time because of Next.js custom document.**

So, during the build time I am getting an error saying, Also I have the `_document.js` in `pages/_document.js`.

```
next/document should not be imported outside of pages/_document.js. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page.
```

[image]

**Please help me!**

**EDIT**

Update next and eslint-config-next to version 11.1.3-canary.7

Comment: Search around if you see `next/document` laying somewhere else?

Comment: No, there's not

Comment: This is a known issue, try to update as my answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **This is a [known issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28596) from the latest Nextjs update**

Quote from Nextjs team:

> This is fixed in [#28745](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/28745) and works in 11.1.3-canary.7. Please upgrade to that version if you're experiencing this issue and if you're still seeing the same error, make sure to clear your cache (next lint --no-cache).

---

### **Conclude:**

You need to update `Nextjs` and `eslint-config-next` to **11.1.3-canary.7** and don't forget to clear cache `next lint --no-cache`

Comment: How comes? Did you update to that version and clear cache?

Comment: Ok, let me try again

Comment: Sure, Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Srry, I am a bit late. just changed ```next and eslint-config-next``` to version ```11.1.3-canary.7```

Answer (score 31):

A known issue that is fixed in [#28596](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28596)

If you don't want to update to the canary versions and still keep working normally just exclude it from your `.eslintrc.json` rules:

```
"rules": {
    "@next/next/no-document-import-in-page": "off"
}
```

More info on how to exclude rules here: [disabling-rules](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules)

Comment: Thank you, this solution solved my issue

Comment: Still facing this issue on version 13.5.4. Was facing a different issue with import on the latest next 14.1.0 tried to make create an issue on the github repository but turns out codesandbox is not working in itself so I can't share the steps to reproduce. Might have to create an issue for that also. Strange weekend.