# Next.js Returning error on build with styled components _document.js

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm using a _document.js to secure that the nextjs will render the page using styled-components(this solve the break on reload), but i'm getting to errors.

I tried to solve it by upgrading next, react and also canary, but without sucess.

Bellow you can find the code and also the errors displayed.

```
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

        try {
            ctx.renderPage = () =>
                originalRenderPage({
                    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
                        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
                });

            const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
            return {
                ...initialProps,
                styles: (
                    <>
                        {initialProps.styles}
                        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
                    </>
                ),
            };
        } finally {
            sheet.seal();
        }
    }
}
```

Errors displayed:

```
./pages/_document.js
1:1  Error: next/document should not be imported outside of pages/_document.js. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page.  @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
12:27  Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs - importing next/document outside of pages/\_document error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061240/nextjs-importing-next-document-outside-of-pages-document-error)

Comment: I just tried this and deleted the node_modules and next folder, but still same error, just deactivate lint to get the build working...

Also got this Component definition is missing display name issue that i could not solve either.